# Does Node.JS's functionality make Namespaces in Typescript pointless?

Tags: typescript

I've been studying the Typescript documentation and am on the modules and namespaces part.  I did some additional research into internal and external modules in Typescript 1.5 to see if that provided a clearer distinction between the two which it did only a little.

So far my understanding of `namespaces` is that they're modules defined inside a module that stay hidden from other modules unless distinctly exported and imported.  While `modules` are just modules that can be used anywhere.  I got to the part about `ambient modules` and how to use them and it really has me wondering why the two exist.

I've been using `Node.JS` with `Angular2`, I've noticed they mention AMD, System and Require JS, which I haven't used, so I'm wondering if the distinction is of more importance when using one of those rather than Node.  So far from what I can see both `Namespaces` and `Ambient Modules` work in Node, though they suggest using modules to prevent confusing the code, but they still go on about how namespaces can still be useful, I just can't understand how.  I started looking backwards to older versions because the new version seems to assume one is already familiar with those things and are just bringing them up to speed.  Can someone help shed some light on this?

Answer (score 1):

As you have learned, `namespace` should be used only for declaring the internal structure of your code nowadays.

In the past, it is used to describe the whole application structure, just like "global namespace" in JS and namespace in other languages such as Java and C#.

One way to use `namespace` in TypeScript nowadays is to group and define interfaces and sub-classes:

```
export class Foo {
  constructor(public option: Foo.Options) { }
}

export namespace Foo {
  export interface Options {
    foo: string
  }
}
```